# Determining the Number of Restrictions in an F-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, restrictions

I understand that with $H_0$:

$$b_1 = 0,\ b_2 = 0,\ b_3 = 0$$

the number of restrictions ($q$) is 3.

However, with $H_1$:

$$b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 0$$

is the number of restrictions now 1?

Comment: Hmm--I count three equality signs in the first example and one in the second.

Answer (score 1):

In the second, we are testing one linear restriction, so q should be one.